# Nethereum: is there a way to build/compile smart contracts from visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ethereum

I am starting to play around with AWS Ethereum using Nethereum in my ASP .NET Core project, and am wondering if there is a way to compile smart contracts from visual studio? I see there is an extension for visual studio code but haven't seen anything for visual studio? Or is there a way to compile in code using Nethereum.Web3?

Comment: The author of Nethereum has also written a great VS Code extension for working with solidity : https://github.com/juanfranblanco/vscode-solidity/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Thanks, I saw that but I was wondering if there was something similar for VS?